XAMPP Wordpress website
I have followed the directions of XAMPP, set up the database and downloaded Wordpress. I can get the website up under http://localhost/site1. I work on it and then the next day when I try to work on it it won't allow me. I have tried reinstalling everything several times. What am I doing wrong and why do I get shut out after it working once?

Hi @Dianne Thomas - I assume you've started the Apache and MySQL modules in XAMPP? If so - can you elaborate a bit more on what error you get when trying to work on your site?

I have tried to change the ports in Config in XAMPP and I still cannot get to localhost...

Changing ports in XAMPP is a hassle, if I remember correctly. I moved away from XAMPP because it caused me so many issues. I have ~200 local sites - and XAMPP started acting weird. I started using Laragon instead. It's so easy to set up - and I've never faced any issues. Maybe give it a shot?
